# Is it a good practice to write many queries inside the same package in PL/SQL, if not, is there a good way to do it..?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a PL/SQL package to populate a table, that will calculate several metrics depending on the formula(querying from different tables), but the package i end up with is full of select statements from different tables.
is there any other way of clubbing all those queries together without making the code too much complex (i love simplicity).

Please suggest.

--a developer in distress

Comment: Maybe this it will help you: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-jul/o15plsql-101302.html

Comment: We could probably help you out if you showed us the code.

Comment: It might be possible to combine the queries, depending on your schema. Whether that makes the code simpler or more complicated is hard to tell from what you've told us. Long, rambling, script-style code can usually be better modularised into subprograms (procedures, functions, types etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cursors. For example, you might be tempted to write a bunch of statements one after the other, such as:

```
DECLARE
  nCurrent_balance    CUSTOMER_RUNNING_BALANCE.CURRENT_BALANCE%TYPE;
  nTotal_credit_line  CUSTOMER_CREDIT_LINE.TOTAL_CREDIT_LINE%TYPE;
  nAvailable_credit   CUSTOMER_CREDIT_LINE.AVAILABLE_CREDIT%TYPE;
  strLocation_name    CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.LOCATION_NAME%TYPE;
  strStreet_address_1 CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.STREET_ADDRESS_1%TYPE;
  strCity             CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.CITY%TYPE;
  strState            CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.CITY%TYPE;
  strZip              CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.CITY%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMER)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT CURRENT_BALANCE
        INTO nCurrent_balance
        FROM CUSTOMER_RUNNING_BALANCE rb
        WHERE rb.CUSTOMER_ID = aRow.CUSTOMER_ID;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        nCurrent_balance := NULL;
    END;

    BEGIN
      SELECT TOTAL_CREDIT_LINE, AVAILABLE_CREDIT
        INTO nTotal_credit_Line, nAvailable_credit
        FROM CUSTOMER_CREDIT_LINE cl
        WHERE cl.CUSTOMER_ID = aRow.CUSTOMER_ID;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        nTotal_credit_line := NULL;
        nAvailable_credit := NULL;
    END;

    BEGIN
      SELECT LOCATION_NAME,
             STREET_ADDRESS_1,
             CITY,
             STATE,
             ZIP
        INTO strLocation_name,
             strStreet_address_1,
             strCity,
             strState,
             strZip
        FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ca
        WHERE ca.CUSTOMER_ID = aRow.CUSTOMER_ID AND
              ca.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'HEADQUARTERS';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        strLocation_name := NULL;
        strStreet_address_1 := NULL;
        strCity := NULL;
        strState := NULL;
        strZip := NULL;
    END;

    // Do something useful with the data here
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Ick. Here we have a cursor and a bunch of individual SELECT statements pulling data from three additional sources into individually declared variables. There's a lot of lines of code here, but most of it is pretty much useless - except that it's all required due to the way this is written - **AND** there's a huge, glaring, and potentially fatal coding bug in this, although the code *may* run just fine - can you spot it? :-)

Using a cursor to join the tables together would reduce the code volume a lot, eliminate the need for all those exception handlers, and would completely eliminate the chance to make the bug above:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT c.CUSTOMER_ID,
                      rb.CURRENT_BALANCE,
                      cl.TOTAL_CREDIT_LINE,
                      cl.AVAILABLE_CREDIT,
                      ca.LOCATION_NAME,
                      ca.STREET_ADDRESS_1,
                      ca.CITY,
                      ca.STATE,
                      ca.ZIP
                 FROM CUSTOMER c
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_RUNNING_BALANCE rb
                   ON rb.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_CREDIT_LINE cl
                   ON cl.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ca
                   ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND
                      ca.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'HEADQUARTERS')
  LOOP
    // Do something useful with the data here
  END LOOP;
END;
```

So - 59 lines of code in the first example, compared to 22 in the second. In the second example the relationships between the tables are clearly spelled out by the cursor. And the error in the first example (a classic cut-and-paste bug I actually made when writing it :-) is impossible to make in the second.

Relational databases are built to process queries such as the cursor in the second example quickly and efficiently. And by using a query you're cutting down on the number of occasions where